# Overriding auto API mappings in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scaladoc

I have a few libraries that depend on [Cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats). Let's say the new Cats 0.4.0 release has the wrong `apiURL` value in its POM. I don't want my API docs to break, so I provide the URL mapping with `apiMappings`:

```
  ..
  autoAPIMappings := false,
  apiMappings ++= (fullClasspath in Compile).value.flatMap(
    entry => entry.get(moduleID.key).map(entry -> _)
  ).collectFirst {
    case (entry, module)
      if module.organization == "org.typelevel" &&
        module.name.startsWith("cats-") =>
          entry.data
  }.map(_ -> url("https://typelevel.org/cats/api/")).toMap,
  apiURL := Some(url("https://travisbrown.github.io/iteratee/api/")),
  ...
```

This works just fine for links to Cats types in my API docs, but it means that I lose links for types from the standard library and other dependencies. If I change `autoAPIMappings` to `true`, though, my custom mapping is gone.

This doesn't make any sense to me—it seems like of course explicitly defined mappings shouldn't be overridden by mappings that are automatically pulled from dependency POMs.

Can I use `autoAPIMappings` but override it for specific dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because `apiMappings` is redefined for the `doc` task, and appends mappings when you set `autoAPImappings := true`, and thus overrides yours, which are defined in the Global scope.

This should work:

```
apiMappings in doc := ...
```

Comment: Thanks!—this sounds reasonable, and I'll try it out to confirm asap.